# Chrome commands API

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've loaded this sample extension from Chrome docs which uses the commands API.

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Sample Extension Commands extension",
  "description": "Press Ctrl+Shift+F (Command+Shift+F on a Mac) to open the browser action popup, press Ctrl+Shift+Y to send an event (Command+Shift+Y on a Mac).",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "browser_action.html"
  },
  "commands": {
    "toggle-feature": {
      "suggested_key": { "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y" },
      "description": "Send a 'toggle-feature' event to the extension"
    },
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  console.log('onCommand event received for message: ', command);
});
```

Very simple, yet the listener callback is not getting triggered - I get no output in the console, nor any errors. If I use other API, for example tabs, my listeners are getting triggered as they should, it's just the commands API that doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you didn't do it yet, go to `chrome://extensions` and check if your keys are effectively assigned to your commands using the 'Keyboard shortcuts' link at the bottom right.

Comment: All right, I absolutely didn't know about that "Keyboard shortcuts" link. So I set my shortcut there and now it works. So what's the "suggested_key" option good for? It's not even shown in the "Keyboard shortcuts" window as a suggested option. By the way, thank you

Comment: Are you working with an unpacked extension? You need to remove and re add the extension for suggested shorcut keys to be considered.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Commenter [rsanchez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1507998/rsanchez) provides the correct answer:

> Are you working with an unpacked extension? You need to remove and re-add the extension for suggested shorcut keys to be considered.

Comment: Unfortunately no, at least for the current version (Chrome 34) the user must change these shortcuts manually using the link "Keyboard shortcuts" at the bottom of this page: chrome://extensions/ - Note that when installing the extension for the first time all the hotkeys will be added, but subsequent changes will not be.

Comment: Would have taken forever to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue and these suggestions didn't help. Here's what I figured out: since you declared the script with the listener in the `background: {}` section, it logs to a background page. You can see that log specifically by clicking "Inspect background page" right below the extension at the `chrome://extensions`. that's where the listener logs to.