# Chrome Extension keyboard commands don't seem to be registering

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing a Chrome Extension with Chrome 34 (ie, dev channel), and the new [chrome.commands API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands), mainly to get media key support.

In my manifest.json, I'm currently just using the example code given in the official docs:

```
"commands": {
  "toggle-feature-foo": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y",
      "mac": "Command+Shift+Y"
    },
    "description": "Toggle feature foo"
  }
}
```

In my background page:

```
chrome.commands.getAll(function(commands){
  console.log(commands)
})

chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
  console.log('Command:', command);
)}
```

Firstly, the keyboard shortcuts aren't registered:

```
Array[1]
 0: Object
   description: "Toggle feature foo"
   name: "toggle-feature-foo"
   shortcut: ""
```

Note how 'shortcut' is blank. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#method-getAll mentions the shortcut is only shown if it is 'active'. but I'm not sure why the shortcut wouldn't be 'active' (I'm using OS X 10.9, if that matters).

Secondly, actually hitting Cmd Shift Y, or Ctrl Shift Y, doesn't fire the event in the background page.

**How can I make keyboard commands be received by my background page**?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19599717/95735

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked the **keyboard shortcuts** box on the bottom of the extensions page to verify that your suggested keys are actually set there?

I ran into a similar problem...when I loaded my unpacked extension for development the suggested keys were **not** set, even if the key was available and defined in the manifest. I had to manually go and set the keys myself in the extension page. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I couldn't find any answers from searches. Also, when I published my extension on the chrome store, the suggested key's worked and were set automatically...so this seems to happen in dev mode only.

Comment: Thanks @berrberr! The official docs don't mention the Keyboard Shortcuts in the extensions page. The only problem I have now is that the media keys (eg, play pause) don't actually work when setting shortcuts - according to the docs, they should be fine too. Will see if the store is any different from dev mode...

Comment: Anybody reassure me whether dev mode is not going to register shortcut keys automatically?

Comment: If your shortcuts are not registering just remove and load unpacked extension again  :)