# Chrome Commands API not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been trying to get the chrome commands api to work, with no success.

I know about both common problems that people are having:

1. If you change the command keys in the manifest file you need to remove and reinstall it for the changes to take effect.
2. Even if you do this, you may also need to scroll down on the extensions page, click the keyboard shortcuts link, and set the commands manually.

I have tried both solutions, even though I'm not sure that the second is still necessary. When I first load the extension, the commands are already loaded and set to the keys I specified in my manifest file.

I have even downloaded the sample commands extension, and tried the commands there.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/commands.zip

The only even that triggers correctly is the browser action. The other command in the example does not work. It does not trigger a console log as far as I can see.

Anybody know whats up?

Edit:

It seems logical to me that the console log would happen in the tab that I had active, but apparently not.

Xan's comment got me thinking, so I added an alert to the command listener in the background.js file of the sample extension.

Sure enough, the alert was triggered. No console log though. No idea where my log is getting sent, but the API is working... just without console output.

Check out Xan's comments for where the log is actually being sent

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right console?

Comment: You got me thinking, thanks Xan. Check my edits above.

Comment: It's being logged to the extension's background page console, which is accessible from `chrome://extensions` in Developer mode

Comment: See the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) for more information.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19599717/95735